# Blender shows wrong items on the material tab

Tags: materials

I am trying to figure out, why my blender is showing the wrong lists in the material tab when I add new material.

[image: Wrong Display]

When it should display my principal BSDF on my materials tab.

[image: Principal BSDF Shader]

Comment: Is your render engine set to workbench by any chance?

Comment: Yea, it was set to workbench. Changed it to eevee and now it works! Thanks